# How to find in what application a workspace image from oracle apex has been used

Tags: oracle, image, oracle-apex, workspace

I'm working on an APEX WORKSPACE with many legacy applications. In my shared components I have a lot of workspace images that I can not tell which applications are using or not. There is a way to search the apex or the database for components or codes using these images? The only way to do this I have found so far is to search application by application but this will take forever.

Thanks.

Comment: In the latest versions of apex (5.0 and later), you can click APP BUILDER >> In the upper right corner there is a search field >> what you put there will be searched in all applications. This field is contextual, so if you enter an application the search will no longer be in all applications, but only in the one you are viewing.

Comment: I'm using APEX 4.2.6 and it worked like you sad. I just had to log out, log in and then search before clicking on any application in the list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As romeuBraga suggested, you can use the Designer's search function.  If you have exports of all your applications in source code control (you do, don't you?), you can check them out to a directory and grep through them for each images filename.